# If I create a dataLayer vairable in GTM to capture a dynamic value, the event pixel (part of CM floodlight) needs to be placed on site, correct?

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, cm, dv360

I am implementing Campaign Manager floodlight tags in Google Tag Manager. As I am trying to capture dynamic values, do I create a dataLayer variable with double brackets, ex: {{cost}} in GTM, then request the event pixel be placed on site? Will the gloabl snippet have to be implemented on site too, or no since the GTM container is linked to DV360?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should really clarify things, but I'll try crystal-balling it.

1. In order for you to capture dynamic variables in dataLayer, you first need to make sure the variable has been pushed into it (typically by the front-end team or a plugin).
2. To use a dataLayer variable, you create a corresponding Data Layer Variable in GTM. See the screenshot: [image]
3. When you deploy a pixel and you need to use eye color in it using javascript, you get the value by referencing the name of the GTM variable rather than what's in DL: `{{DLV - Eye Color}}`
4. Finally, timing. When your pixel firing trigger is being triggered, your dynamic values should already be available. Otherwise, you'll not be getting them, sending pixels with no dynamic values.